# List of class instances in python

Tags: python, deep-copy

I am new to python, and more used to C++. I want to create a list of instances and did the following:

```
from copy import deepcopy

class C:
    c1=""
    c2=""

Cs=[]
C.c1="Hello"
C.c2="World"
Cs.append(deepcopy(C))

C.c1="Why"
C.c2="this?"
Cs.append(deepcopy(C))

for c in Cs:
    print (c.c1, c.c2)
```

I expected the following output:

```
Hello World
Why this?
```

but got:

```
Why this?
Why this?
```

Why is the deep copy not working?

Comment: BTW, you aren't making any instances of that `C` class. Python classes work a little differently to C++.

Answer (score 2):

there is only one (`static` in the Java/C++ sense) copy of the c1 and c2 variables. Read https://www.toptal.com/python/python-class-attributes-an-overly-thorough-guide and sprinkle more `self`s in your code to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this tutorial. I have changed my code to

    from copy import deepcopy
    
    class C:
        pass
    
    Cs=[]
    iC=C()
    iC.c1="Hello"
    iC.c2="World"
    Cs.append(deepcopy(iC))
     
    iC.c1="Why"
    iC.c2="this?"
    Cs.append(deepcopy(iC))
    
    for c in Cs:
        print (c.c1, c.c2)`

Is this the preferred way of doing such a thing in python?